# GTK UI Looks different when running from bundle and when running from Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have C# App using Mono framework and GTK for UI.When i run it from Xamarin Studio it looks like this

[image]

I have bundled Mono and GTK into a standalone bundle.When running from it it looks different.

[image]

Which one looks more native to the OSX Platform? If its the first one,then how can i get the same look and feel in the bundled App.

Comment: The bundle is simply using a different theme. I don't know how you configure what themes are included with the bundle, but it should be possible. Neither of them are native; if you want to look native, you'll have to find an OS X lookalike theme (or switch to using Cocoa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GTK 2 Theming Options:**

- Use the default system theme
- Per user theming via `~/.gtkrc`
- Per application theming via GTK api
- Per application theming via environment var

**GTK 2 Theming:**

Theming is handled in GTK 2 via resource files with the master normally named 'gtkrc'. These resources files can be standalone, include other resources files and reference external images (icons), etc....  The internals of `gtkrc`-based files are out-of-scope here, but there are plenty of references on the web for GTK 2.0 resources/theming.

**Mono w/ GTK 2:**

Mono on OS-X installs a default GTK2 theme (`gtkrc`) and few alternative themes:

Location : `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1`

```
find . -name "gtkrc"
./etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
./share/themes/bubble/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
./share/themes/Clearlooks/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
./share/themes/Mac/gtk-2.0-key/gtkrc
./share/themes/Quartz/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
./share/themes/Xamarin/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

The one located in the `<Mono/Version>/etc/gtk-2.0` is the default (Tango style) while one of the alternatives is 'Xamarin' and is the one that is used to stylize Xamarin Studio (internally named "Mac Theme for Xamarian").

As for controlling which theme is applied to your application, you can allow the user to control it via $HOME directory based `.gtkrc` files (IMHO: how many users really know how to do that or would even what to and the support nightmares of 'expert' end-users tweaking the UI, I prefer locking the UIX experience to something uniform to all users, but, again, that is just my opition).

You are supposed to be able to set environment var `GTK2_RC_FILES` in your app startup script, but I never had any luck with this.

Note: The env. var. `GTK_THEME` does work in GTK3 (but Mono is GTK2 bound)

- Ref: Very good Stack exchange related to this @ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14129/gtk-enable-set-dark-theme-on-a-per-application-basis
- Ref: Another good Q/A : [GTK+ application specific skin possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956796/gtk-application-specific-skin-possible)

**Application theming via GTK api:**

With your application you can assign GTK to use one of the Mono installed themes or one that your application provides.

**BEFORE** the `Gtk.Application.Init()` you can do the following to assign the gtkrc file:

```
Gtk.Rc.AddDefaultFile ({gtkrcFile}); 
Gtk.Rc.Parse ({gtkrcFile});
```

If you have your own theme, bundle the files (gtkrc, other included gtkrc files, icons, images, etc...) inside your `.app`. Normally these would be bundled inside the `Contents\Resource directory and use the above code to assign the`gtkrc` that is in your bundle.

For standalone exe's I have also have used an embedded gtkrc file and extract it to a tmp file a runtime:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using Gtk;

namespace themes
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            InitGlobalResourceFile ();
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }

        static void InitGlobalResourceFile ()
        { 
            String gtkResouceFile;

            Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ();
            string[] names = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames ();
            foreach (string name in names) {
                Console.WriteLine (name);
                if (name.Contains ("GtkThemeResource.rc")) {
                    gtkResouceFile = name;
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine ("Gtk Theme Resource not found in manifest");
            }

            var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName ();
            var stream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream (gtkResouceFile);
            string gtkrc;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (stream)) {
                gtkrc = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            }
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter (tmpFile)) {
                outputFile.WriteLine (gtkrc);
            }
            Rc.AddDefaultFile (tmpFile); 
            Rc.Parse (tmpFile); 
        }

    }
}
```

- FYI: The Xamarin GTK2/OS-X theme is maintained here (https://github.com/mono/xamarin-gtk-theme)

Comment: Thanks.I will check and get back.

Comment: I did not embed the file.I just copied the xamarin theme and placed it in the deployment directory and added Gtk.Settings.Default.ThemeName = "Default/gtkrc";
Gtk.Rc.Parse ("Default/gtkrc");

Comment: Also i had to set gtk-button-images= 1 in the theme file to show the image buttons.GTK Does not show this by default in Xamarin Studio or the deployed app.And the Theme named Mac has GTK theme file in some other format.

Comment: I have created the bundle using the xamarin theme and using platypus.Now a new issue has came up.The execution of the App bundle is not consistent.Sometimes it shows the GUI and sometimes the console icon stays there without showing the GUI.What may be wrong?Please help.

Comment: I tried using the Xamarin theme by using Gtk.parse.But the app fails to start at times.Can you please help me.. im stuck here.

Comment: "app fails to start at times" With posting stack traces/logs/Console.app errors/etc... not much anyone can do to help.  :-/

Comment: I have asked a new Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760329/gtk-application-non-consistant-execution-using-xamarin-theme with all the required details.Please help me out.

Comment: I have managed to run the packed application without using the xamarin theme.The mkbundled app works fine on my Mac but when i tested on another Mac i got this exception System.DllNotFoundException: libglib-2.0.dll and its referencing the Bundled Mono (not the lib folder).I tried compiling with the latest version of mono on a new machine,the produced Native code does not even run and produces a ton of errors.Im really really stuck and have spend a lot of time trying to fix it.You are the only person who can help me.Please help me.