# Gtk Application Non-Consistant Execution using Xamarin Theme

Tags: macos, xamarin, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a mkbundled mono app with mono embedded in it.i have created a standalone package from it using platypus.I use the following to load the Mac Theme(Xamarin)

```
Gtk.Rc.Parse ("Default/gtkrc");
```

The theme is the `Xamarin theme` from share/theme/xamarin

The thing is that the application does not launch consitantly when using this theme.It launches randomly.Also im using `gtk-button-images = 1` in theme file to show the buttons.The app works fine with other themes.

What is the problem here?please help.

UPDATE:

I have tried launching the application manually from console by putting 
the following ./script.sh

It launches the program sometimes. Otherwise the console stays there with no output.I have the program window icon on the dock during this ,When i close it i can see the following output on the console

```
./script.sh: line 3:   830 Terminated: 15       ./myapp
```

The contents in the script are as follows

```
VAR=`pwd`
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$VAR/lib:/usr/lib"
./myapp
```

On Random successful execution of the program and only upon closing the program.I get the following on the console

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on a toplevel widget


Unhandled Exception:
System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject+MonoMac_Disposer::.ctor(System.IntPtr)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (IntPtr ptr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.NSObjectMarshaler`1[MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject].MarshalNativeToManaged (IntPtr handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) object:[MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject:IntPtr NativeRetain()] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr_bool (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,bool)
  at MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Im stuck here.Please help me.